# Backslash not working in regex when stored in an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I'm working on a simple lexical analyser for a project and I'm using an array to store regex patterns as strings.

I test each regex pattern individually to make sure I get the correct output when checking a line of a file.

The problem is, once I stored these strings in an array I started getting several errors. Mainly when searching for strings that start with backslash `\`.

This is my Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@PATTERNS = ("\\begin", "\\end", "{", "}", "<\d+(\.\d+)?>", "<p>", "<\\p>", ".*", "%%+", "<%", "%>") ;

print "Enter some text: ";
chomp( $input = <> );

print test();

sub test() {

    my $arrSize = @PATTERNS;

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < $arrSize; $i++ ) {

        if ( $input =~ /$PATTERNS[$i]/gi ) {
            print "good input\n";
        }
        else {
            print "bad input\n";
        }
    }

}
```

This above is my test file to read lines I manually type in to check regex expression and give me a good input if it matches or bad input if it doesn't.

Perl continues to skip over my backslashes no matter how I use it in each string.

I'm using the default Perl v5.18.2 that is installed with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program that you write

Comment: I have tried to improve your question, but the paragraph starting *"This is my test file"* doesn't make sense. Please will you fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in double quotes are "interpolated" in Perl. Backslash has a special meaning here. If you want to store regular expressions in an array, it's better to use the `qr//` construct:

```
my @PATTERNS = ( qr/\\begin/,
                 qr/\\end/,
                 qr/{/,
                 qr/}/,
                 qr/<\d+(\.\d+)?>/,
                 qr/<p>/,
                 qr(</p>), # I assumed HTML/PHP, so replaced \p.
                 qr/.*/,
                 qr/%%+/,
                 qr/<%/,
                 qr/%>/,
               ) ;
```

You should use [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings), they would warn you against some mistakes you made:

```
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at /home/choroba/1.pl line 5.
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at /home/choroba/1.pl line 5.
main::test() called too early to check prototype at /home/choroba/1.pl line 10.
```

Comment: You should explain that you have assumed the input to be HTML

Comment: Rather a combination of TeX, php and something :-)

Comment: @choroba: I'm talking specifically about `# Not \p!`. It's always dangerous to alter anything but white space from the OP's post. But I agree, and I'm worried about the bigger question that's sure to come ...